# Do you need to have past travel history to get your New Zealand visa approved?

Tags: visas, new-zealand

Do you need to have past travel history to get your New Zealand visa approved? My aunt is a New Zealand citizen and sponsoring me next year. I'm worried they won't approve my visa because I haven't travelled before.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not necessary to have past travel experience to get a visa for New Zealand.

Whether you are approved or not depends on your personal circumstances, the circumstances of your sponsor, the type of visa you are applying for, and whether there are any annual quotas on the number of that type of visa that are issued.